# Problem 15 from Herstein's book

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $S$ and $T$ we declare $S<T$ if there is a mapping of $T$ *onto* $S$ but *no* mapping of $S$ *onto* $T$. Prove that if $S<T$ and $T<U$ then $S<U$.

**My Proof:** Since $S<T$ then $\exists$ *onto* mapping $f_1:T\to S$ and since $T<U$ then $\exists$ *onto* mapping $f_2:U\to T$ then mapping $f_1\circ f_2:U\to S$ is also *onto* mapping. We have done with the first part of proposition.

But how to prove that no mapping from $S$ to $U$ is onto. I have tried to do it by contradiction but no results.

Can anyone help please with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g:S \to U$ which is onto. Then $f_2 \circ g$ is onto $T$, a contradiction.

Comment: I answered 22 seconds before you did. :-)

Comment: Nice answer. I did not think that it is so easy. I totally forgot to consider its composition with $f_2$ function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Filburt you got my +1

Comment: @gt6989b So you got mine

Comment: @RFZ took more than a split second to formalize -- it was clear from the start you want to contradict absence of onto maps on $T$, just was not sure how initially...

Comment: $f_2 \circ g$, not $g \circ f_2$.

Comment: @AriBrodsky fixed, thank you

Answer (score 9):

Suppose that there exist an onto map $f:S\to U$. Since $T<U$, there exist an onto map $f_0:U\to T.$ So $f_0\circ f:S\to T$ is onto and, what is a contradiction since $S<T$.